# Wheelchair lift for vehicle which can be replaced by seats

Tags: accessories

I am worried I'm not in the right forum, so please feel free to transfer me over to somewhere else in StackExchange!

I have a child can walk to some degree, but generally is in a wheelchair. I am looking to buy a car with a wheelchair lift into the back of the car. I have three other children (with no disabilities), so I need 3 seats in the middle of the car, as well as the lift in the back for my disabled son. Something looking like this:

[image]

My question is that sometimes we don't need the lift. On certain days he can walk ok, and we want him to be able to sit in the car on a normal seat. Is there a model of a car that even though it has a lift for wheelchairs on the back of it, a seat can easily be screwed in the place, allowing 3 seats for kids in the back, and an additional 'temporary' seat in the back, where the wheelchair lift is. I do need the ability for him to sit in the car in the wheel chair.

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Probably the best option is a wheelchair rack connected to a trailer hitch on the outside of the vehicle. Use the wheel chair when needed?

Comment: But i really need the option that sometimes he sits in the car in his wheel chair, and I don't think your suggestion helps for this, right?

Comment: You might edit you question to clarify your specific needs of him needing to be in the wheelchair in the vehicle sometimes. I am sure there is a solution.

Comment: Perhaps something with a Nissan NV200 Evalia as a base vehicle, as the rear seats are turnable sideways when folded. But you need to speak with the company that installs the wheelchair lift

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly I have seen exactly what you require.

There are few variations but basically they consist of either a fold out ramp, a low profile lift or a ramp combined with aftermarket air suspension to aid access. These have the benefit of taking so little room they can be left in place even when the fixed seats are fitted.

Then there are quick release fittings attached to the floor of the vehicle,
when using the wheel chair you clip on a racket type belt to the quick release fittings to secure the chair. When not using the chair you then put in your seat or bench seat which also has quick release fittings that clip into the ones on the floor.

There are also ramps where you cut out the rear section of the floor so it folds down flat so the seats go over the top, so the ramp takes up no room at all.

I'll have a look through my paperwork and see if I can find the name of the company that produces the equipment I have seen, I'll update when I find it.

Comment: Thanks so much, you have given me a lot to look into. Will appreciate any links or updates, or any pics to help me picture the options.